# Sticking to one field vs rotation

Tags: career-development, technology

I have just finished education and started to work. I have a few questions I need to be clear about:

1. The very basic thing is sticking to one technology or one area of development vs rotation. Is it better to gain experience in one area (e.g development for Android or Game Development for instance) or keep on switching or trying different things and exploring? If rotation should be done (as things become obsolete with time as well) how often?
2. How does having a broader experience of different fields and technologies measure up against a long experience of single technology. And how does it measure up against having a broad experience of a single area (like developing games for different platforms). I am asking in context of when someone applies for a job, how are these things evaluated and what impression about a professional they leave.

Comment: I'm thinking this question strays too much toward the "not constructive" part of our [faq#dontask]. It's hard to say anything concrete about such a broad question. Some positions value depth, some value breadth. Even different recruiters/etc have different expectations.

Comment: Agreeing with @Rarity's comments above; we would welcome edits to make this much less broad, at which time the community can vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mention Android, but that has only been in use for about 4 years. You may have a goal of focusing on one area and then have the entire market change. There are developers with years of experience developing software for Palm, RIM, who may have trouble getting jobs developing for Android, iOS, and Windows phones.

If you are just out of school, focus on what can help you grow in your company. If you don't see a clear path to growth in the technology you know, decide if it is better to learn a new technology or move to a different company. Sometimes a company abandons a technology because they don't see themselves in that market anymore.

The market and the changes in technology will dictate if switching is necessary. When you do jump make sure you also try to gain authority, the goal is to become a senior developer or manager, not just a programmer with 2 years experience in 10 technologies.

The balance between years in one technology and the years spread across a few technologies is hard to predict. Some projects are have small staffs: you may find yourself writing all the code, testing all the code and installing all the code. On a larger project you only be responsible for speeding up the openGL routines. The first project requires broad experience, the second project needs expert level.

The choices you make along the path will constantly open and close future doors. You just can't predict which ones they will be beyond the near term.

Comment: Market obviously changes, so you raised an interesting point that the objective should be a senior developer or a manager after 10 years not a developer of 10 technologies. So how to keep ascending in that direction or at least keep a higher position when joining a new team or a new company working in a different technology/platform? Also what are the indicators that the technology is going to be phased out (it is difficult and there maybe no general answer, but a little idea about how to identify the trend with sufficient time to switch would be helpful)

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I'm not sure there's a right answer here.

Back in the day, I chose heavy rotation via a corporate program.  It was a real boost to my career, because it gave me a breadth of skills and make it easier in the long run for me to see a big picture and to have enough technical chops for almost any occasion.  It's helped my career numerous times - I still fall back on some of those experiences 15 years later.

However, if I was looking at someone's resume and they had bounced around a lot without the benefit of being in a corporate program and/or without showing that they were loyal to a single company - it would raise some red flags for me.  It takes 3 months to make an employee minimally competent and in a technical world, you don't really expect to break even on your investment in someone for at least a year.  So... if I see that a candidate has focused too much on rotation, without digging in and being productive in a single role, I get nervous as a hiring manager, because the candidate may do similarly on my team.

So -- I'd say in an ideal world you get both.  You strive to learn a breadth of technology, but while pursuing a singular goal.  You also should be around long enough to see the outcome of the technical decisions you make.  No technical choice is perfect, and learning how your work plays out in the long run is key to moving forward in a technical path.

Even without a snazzy corporate program, I think there's plenty of opportunities for this - most development positions involve learning a range of skills - even within a single programming language.  And many jobs these days involve integrating a pretty wide variety of technologies.

I would say we have hit the end of the days when being a guru in a single technical domain will guarantee success.  People need a depth of understanding about the critical aspects of their field, but coming "the guy who knows everything about X technology" is becoming a risky proposition given how fast technology requirements are changing these days.

Answer (score 1):

In case of applying for a job as per the company's requirement your knowledge of different technologies will matter. e.g. If a company deals with various technologies as per the client's requirement (This is the case with small and middle level org) then the candidate having knowledge of different technologies is best suited.

where as if you are heading towards MNCs there are less chances of having different technologies stand you out in the crowd because their tools and frameworks are already beyond the programming languages.

Though you can keep exploring multiple technologies and you should explore most in one you are working on. My suggestion is in the spare time you can always have a look at different technologies and sky is the limit